# Find out the odd value and meet criteria in java

Tags: java, function

I would like to write a function in java that receives a parameter and returns 1 or 0, in the following conditions:

1. If the length of the array is odd, return 1 if the sum of the odd numbers is greater than the sum of the even numbers, and 0 otherwise.
2. If the length of the array is even, check the largest number less or equal then 10. If it is odd, return 1. If it is even, return 0.

For example, using the following arrays:

```
array1 = {13, 4, 7, 2, 8}
array2 = {11, 7, 4, 2, 3, 10}
```

The first array returns 1, because there `13(odd) + 7(odd)` = 20 is greater then `4 + 2 + 8` = 14.
The second array returns 0, because there `11, 7` are odd but, 10 is greater then 7.

What I already tried, please check below:

```
   public static int isOddHeavy(int[] arr) {
        int summationOd = 0;
        int summationEv = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                summationOd = sumOddEven(arr);
            } else {
                summationEv = sumOddEven(arr);
            }
        }

        if(summationOd > summationEv) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    public static int sumOddEven(int[] arr) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            total += arr[i];
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: I don't get the *"return 0, because there 11, 7 are odd but, 10 is greater then 7"* part.

Comment: what about `3` isn't it odd in `array2` ?

Comment: Here I would not like to summation of odd numbers here. Actually, I would not like to check odd numbers which is greater than 10. If I get odd number greater than 10 then I have to check which odd smaller than 10. Do you get my point?

Comment: @Rustam Actually, here is another condition. I will not move to less than if I found a greater odd number of an array which is smaller than 10. Suppose, I have 9, 7, 5, 3, 1. If I'll take 9 and return 0.

Comment: Also be careful, your for loop in sumOddEven is starting at 1 (second element) instead of 0 (first element).

Comment: Still not getting your 2nd condition. By the way, you are just always summing up all the numbers from index 1 here: `summationOd = sumOddEven(arr);` `and summationEv = sumOddEven(arr);`, since you are passing in the input array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java function that does what you want. Just iterate through the array, updating the variables and check your conditions in the end.

```
    public static int yourFunction(int[] arr) {
        int sumOdd = 0;
        int sumEven = 0;
        int maxOdd = 0;
        int maxEven = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                sumEven += arr[i];
                if (maxEven < arr[i] && arr[i] <= 10)
                    maxEven = arr[i];
            }
            else {
                sumOdd += arr[i];
                if (maxOdd < arr[i] && arr[i] <= 10)
                    maxOdd = arr[i];
            }
        }
        if (arr.length%2 != 0)
            return (sumOdd > sumEven) ? 1 : 0;
        return (maxOdd > maxEven) ? 1 : 0;

    }
```